# Sort a multidimensional-array array in php by two values

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks like below

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [room] => kh-332
        [type] => Computer Lab
        [description] => K Lab
        [availability] => available

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [room] => mh-112
        [type] => Conference Room
        [description] => Chute Room
        [availability] => conflict
        )

[2] => Array
    (
        [room] => mh-227
        [type] => Classroom
        [description] => EMCC Class
        [availability] => available
        )
[3] => Array
    (
        [room] => mh-500
        [type] => Lab
        [description] => Auto Lab
        [availability] => available
        )
[4] => Array
    (
        [room] => mh-125
        [type] => Classroom
        [description] => Accuplacer Testing
        [availability] => conflict
        )
[5] => Array
    (
        [room] => mh-225
        [type] => Computer Lab
        [description] => Kaplan Testing 
        [availability] => available
        )
[6] => Array
    (
        [room] => mh-111
        [type] => Conference Room
        [description] => Video Conference
        [availability] => conflict
        )
)
```

I need to sort the array first by type, then by room name so that all of the Computer Labs, for example, will grouped in the array, sorted alphabetically by room. I used the function below to sort the array by type, but I am having some difficulty then sorting the type groups alphabetically by room. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
function aasort (&$array, $key) {
$sorter=array();
$ret=array();
reset($array);
foreach ($array as $ii => $va) {
    $sorter[$ii]=$va[$key];
}
asort($sorter);
foreach ($sorter as $ii => $va) {
    $ret[$ii]=$array[$ii];
}
$array=$ret;
}
```

Comment: You should try using [**`usort()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php). Look at Example 2

Answer (score -1):

I did a little more digging into usort() and I find an answer to my question, this worked.

```
usort($merge,function($a,$b){
    $c = strcmp($a['type'],$b['type']);
    $c .= strcmp($a['availability'],$b['availability']);
    $c .= strcmp($a['room'],$b['room']);
    return $c;
});
```